# Saving images to a directory

Tags: objective-c, xcode, nsstring, nsurl, nsfilemanager

Hi I want to save an image to a directory, I pass the NSData and do what I think will save the file in a directory I create but the problem is that it doesn't save. This is what I have so far. Why doesn't the `initWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error:` work, it returns null but the other method I used works? The main problem is `WRITETOURL` which returns a 0 which i think means that the information wasn't stored properly, any tips?

```
     NSFileManager *fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
        NSArray * directoryPaths = [fm URLsForDirectory:NSCachesDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask];
        NSLog(@"%@", directoryPaths);
        NSURL* dirPath = nil;    
        dirPath = [[directoryPaths objectAtIndex:0] URLByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"photos.jpeg"]];
       NSError* theError = nil;
       [fm createDirectoryAtURL:dirPath withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:&theError];

    UIImage* photoToStore = [UIImage imageWithData:photoToSave];

    NSString *pathContainingPhoto = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@.jpeg", UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photoToStore, 1.0)];
    NSError *error = nil;


    BOOL OK = [pathContainingPhoto writeToURL:dirPath atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

    NSLog(@"OK = %d", OK); //Returns 0
    NSLog(@"%@", dirPath);

    //WHY DOESNT THIS VERSION WORK?
    // NSString *pathToFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:dirPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];
    NSLog(@"%@", pathToFile);

      NSString* pathToFile = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:dirPath encoding:nil error:nil];
    NSArray *dirContents = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:pathToFile error:nil];
    NSLog(@"%@", dirContents);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this and int count in .h file and set its intial value count = 0; in viewDidLoad:

```
NSString *stringPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)objectAtIndex:0]stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Image_%d.png",count];
error = nil;
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:stringPath]) // removing item it already exuts
{
   [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:stringPath error:&error];
}

if(photoToSave) // nsdata of image that u have
{
  [photoToSave writeToFile:stringPath atomically:YES];
}
count++; // maintaining count of images
```

Comment: also it claims NSData doesnt declare WRiteToFile?

Comment: also what if I save multiple images in one file, how do I get the contents of a specific piece of data?

Comment: check edited answer and i don't understand the idea of saving multiple images in one file(like all images in one pdf )